# Posterior of $\text{Normal}(\theta,1)$ with a Cauchy prior distribution

Tags: bayesian, accept-reject

If $X \sim N(\theta,1)$ with Cauchy as robust prior

$$\pi(\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+\theta^2)} \qquad -\infty < \theta < \infty$$

What will be the posterior distribution when Cauchy is $(-2 < \theta <2)$. I tried when $C(0,1)$

(2) How to describe a rejection sampler to simulate samples of $\theta$ from $\pi$($\theta$|x), with $\pi$($\theta$) as the proposal distribution and same how to do it in R

So please help to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "find?" I can tell you $\pi(\theta \mid x)$ is proportional to 
$$
f(x \mid \theta) \pi(\theta)  \propto \exp\left[-\frac{(\theta - x)^2}{2} - \log(1 + \theta^2) \right],
$$
but I don't recognize this density. You can use this fact in a number of techniques to sample from the posterior (e.g. accept-reject, importance sampling with resampling, MCMC, etc.).

By the way, your prior is a $\mathcal{C}(0,1)$ prior, which has support $-\infty < \theta < \infty$.

### Edit:

You seem to be interested in accept-reject sampling. Say you're targeting $\pi(\theta \mid x) \propto f(x \mid \theta) \pi(\theta)$, but you want to simulate from the prior. First, check that
$$
\frac{f(x \mid \theta) \pi(\theta)}{\pi(\theta)} \le\sup_{\theta} f(x \mid \theta) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}.
$$
So you want to do the following steps over and over again:

1. Sample $\theta^i \sim \pi(\theta)$
2. Calculate  $f(x \mid \theta^i) (2 \pi)^{1/2}$
3. Draw $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1]$
4. If $U < f(x \mid \theta^i) (2 \pi)^{1/2}$ accept the sample, otherwise throw it away and start again at step 1.

You can also sample from any other $g(\theta)$ that has support on the reals. You just have to find a $c$ (hopefully as small as possible) such that $\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta) \le c g(\theta)$. It works because:

\begin{align*}
&P\left( \theta \le t \bigg\rvert U \le \frac{\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)}{c g(\theta) } \right) \\
&= \frac{P\left( \theta \le t , U \le \frac{\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)}{c g(\theta) } \right)}{P\left(U \le \frac{\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)}{c g(\theta) } \right)} \\
&= \frac{\int_{-\infty}^t \int_0^{ \frac{\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)}{c g(\theta) } }g(\theta)1 \text{d}u \text{d}\theta }{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_0^{ \frac{\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)}{c g(\theta) } }g(\theta)1 \text{d}u \text{d}\theta } \\
&= \frac{\int_{-\infty}^t g(\theta)\frac{\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)}{c g(\theta) }  \text{d}\theta }{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\theta)  \frac{\pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)}{c g(\theta) } \text{d}\theta } \\
&= \frac{\int_{-\infty}^t \pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)  \text{d}\theta }{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \pi(\theta) f(x \mid \theta)\text{d}\theta } \\
&= \pi(\theta \le t \mid x).
\end{align*}
So these **accepted** draws $\theta^1,\theta^2, \ldots, \theta^n$ have as their distribution the posterior of interest, and we never had to figure out the normalizing constant. We did have to figure out an upper bound, though. In my opinion, that's the downside of this method compared with other methods where that step isn't necessary.

Comment: Can you please show the proportional in detail?

Comment: What does this mean "By the way, your prior is a C(0,1) prior, which has support −∞<θ<∞."

Comment: @shuvamagrawal regarding your first comment, multiply the two densities together, and drop any factor that doesn't depend on $\theta$. Regarding your second, I just mentioned that because your phrasing in the question sounded to me like you thought these were two different problems, when they're not. Are you interested in using accept-reject sampling? I just noticed the tag

Comment: Yes I am interested in using accept-reject sampling

Comment: Just asking if C(-5,5) will it change the posterior

Comment: Yes, it will change. The prior you wrote down is a standard Cauchy, though.

Comment: Can you please help for this type? I am facing the problem

Comment: "Are you interested in using accept-reject sampling" So how to use it

Comment: @shuvamagrawal the first step is choosing a proposal distribution. The second step is finding a bound on the ratio between your target and proposal, which can be tricky depending on what your proposal is.

Comment: in this question what is π(θ∣x)

Comment: @shuvamagrawal the posterior distribution

Comment: What will be the posterior distribution for the above question

Comment: @shuvamagrawal I don't know the name of it. My answer details a way you can sample from the distribution without being able to write down the density function

Comment: so the F(theta) you have mentioned is the posterior distribution

Comment: @shuvamagrawal $f(x \mid \theta)$ is the likelihood, not the posterior. $\pi(\theta)$ is the prior. There is no capital $F$

Comment: f(theta) you have mentioned is it the posterior distribution

Comment: Can you show in detail π(θ∣x) with all steps

Comment: @shuvamagrawal let me get rid of that. I can see how that would be confusing

Comment: I believe your initial formula should be $f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)\propto\exp\left[-\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2}\right][1+\theta^2]^{-1}$.  The log of the numerator is $\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2}-\log(1+\theta^2)$ for a single observation.

Comment: @DaveHarris they are one and the same. Watch the missing minus sign in your second expression though

Comment: Ah yes, my brain must have been mush

Comment: one thing how to code the rejection sampler in R, and use it to generate 10, 000 samples from the posterior distribution. with using R function rcauchy to simulate from π(θ) as the proposal distribution

Comment: @shuvamagrawal please post a separate question for other questions

Comment: @Taylor I have since its on hold saying off topic can you please Help

Comment: That's the reason I have edited in this question

Comment: @shuvam comments are not for extended discussion; your original question was answered and that should have been the end of it. Changing an answered question after the fact is not okay. If there's a problem with your other question, *address the issue there*. ie. edit it to make it on topic (by focusing on the aspects within our [scope](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). [You should also be very careful to avoid simply deleting downvoted questions and reposting them (rather than fixing the first one); ultimately you will render yourself unable to post any questions at all.]

Comment: It is also unacceptable to pester people in comments to answer your other questions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by [Taylor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8336/taylor) is excellent, and already correctly gives the posterior kernel, which gives an intractable integral.  If your goal is to find the posterior *density* (as opposed to sampling from the posterior distribution) then you are effectively just looking for the constant-of-integration:

$$H(x) \equiv \frac{1}{\pi} \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2} (\theta - x)^2)}{(1+\theta^2)} d\theta.$$

In this case acceptance-sampling is an inefficient method of numerically estimating the integral, since it discards a lot of generated values.  A more efficient method is to calculate numerically using a large number $m$ of quantiles of the standard normal distribution:

$$\hat{H}_m(x) \equiv \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{1+(x+z_{(k)})^2} \quad \quad \quad z_{(k)} = \Phi^{-1}(\tfrac{2k-1}{2m}).$$

It is simple to establish that $\hat{H}_m \rightarrow H$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$, which gives you the approximate posterior:

$$\pi(\theta|x) \approx \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2} (\theta - x)^2)}{(1+\theta^2) \hat{H}_m(x)} \quad \quad \text{for all } \theta \in \mathbb{R}.$$

---

**Simulating the required constant:** This estimate of the definite integral can be implemented in `R` with a vectorised function of `x` using the code below.  The integral is symmetric about zero so we plot it (on a logarithmic scale) for positive values of $x$.

```
#Create function to estimate definite integral
H <- function(x, m) { P     <- ((1:m) - 1/2)/m;
                      Z     <- qnorm(P, 0, 1);
                      HHAT  <- rep(0, length(x));
                      for (i in 1:length(x)) {
                        DENOM   <- 1 + (x[i]+Z)^2;
                        HHAT[i] <- sqrt(2/pi)*sum(1/DENOM); }
                      HHAT; }

#Plot this function for values of x
library(ggplot2);
library(scales);

theme_update(plot.title    = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0.5),
         plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5),
         axis.title.x  = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5),
         axis.title.y  = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5),
         plot.margin   = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"));

m <- 10^6;
DATA <- data.frame(xx = (0:100),
                   HH = H((0:100), m));
ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = xx, y = HH)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2, colour = 'red') +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x))) +
  ggtitle('Plot of estimated value of integral') + 
  labs(subtitle = paste0('(Quantile sampling with ', 
                         format(m, scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ','), 
                         ' values)')) + 
  xlab('x') + ylab('hat(H)');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Ben. one thing where how to code the rejection sampler in R, and use it to generate 10, 000 samples from the posterior distribution. with using r function rcauchy to simulate from $\pi$($\theta$)

Comment: Can you please help with that

Comment: @shuvam agrawal: My answer does not involve rejection sampling, so I have not coded this.  If you would like to ask a question about coding rejection sampling, please ask it as a new question, rather than in comments.